# How to extract data from multiple tables of MS Access at one time in python, I wrote a code with query, that extract data from 1 table using filters

Tags: python-3.x, ms-access

But I need to extract data from multiple tables in one running of the code
Here is the code which I wrote:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

database_file = input("Enter the path to the database file: ")
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=' + database_file + ';'
)

while True:
    print("MENU:\n 1.Query for checking the number of masterCodes in each WBID\n 2.Plot with this data")
    num1 = int(input("Enter your response: "))
    if num1 == 1:
        table_name = input("Enter the name of the table: ")
        column_to_count = input("Enter the name of the column to count the variables in: ")
        condition_column = input("Enter the name of the column to use as a condition: ")
        condition_value = input("Enter the value to use as a condition: ")
        pd.options.display.max_rows = None
#The problem in the line below, I have to get access not only one table, but 4. How I can do that?
        query = "SELECT " + column_to_count + ", " + condition_column + " FROM "+ table_name+ " WHERE " + condition_column + " = '" + condition_value + "'"
        df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
    if num1 == 2:
        print("Going to next steps")
        break
    # Count the number of occurrences of each variable in the column
    counts = df[column_to_count].value_counts()
    print(counts)

#query = "SELECT year, result,wbid FROM rawData1 WHERE (wbid = '1573A' and masterCode = 'DO')"
while True:
    print("MENU:\n 1.QUERY\n 2.EXIT")
    num = int(input("Enter your response: "))
    if num == 1:
        row = input("Enter row : ")
        column = input("Enter column : ")
        condition = input("Enter condition : ")
        query = "SELECT " + row + ", " + column + " FROM rawData1 Where (" + condition + ")"
        #query = input("Enter your query: ")
    if num == 2:
        print("Program is completed")
        break
    print(query)
    df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
    print(df)

    df = df.sort_values(by='year')
    x = df['year']
    y = df['result']

    plt.plot(x, y)

    plt.xlabel(row)
    plt.ylabel(column)
    plt.title("Plot Title")

    plt.show()
```

The problem in the line below, I have to get access not only one table, but 4. How I can do that?
`query = "SELECT " + column_to_count + ", " + condition_column + " FROM "+ table_name+ " WHERE " + condition_column + " = '" + condition_value + "'"`
table_name give me access only to one table in MS Access.

Comment: Are these tables related? What is nature of relationships? Build SQL statement that joins tables?

Comment: Yes, all 4 tables have same columns and its names, but with different values

Comment: select_statements = [
         "SELECT * FROM rawData1",
         "UNION SELECT * FROM rawData2",
         "UNION SELECT * FROM rawData3",
         "UNION SELECT * FROM rawData4"
     ]
        union_query = " ".join(select_statements)

I tried to use this, but it didn't help to join, literally code gives me error

Comment: What error? If tables have same columns and you want to have one dataset, that does sound like UNION. Because you use wildcard instead of specifying fields, they must be in same order in table design. Why don't you do one continuous SQL statement instead of concatenation? Why do you have 4 tables to begin with instead of one table with another field to identify groups?